# Combining two dataframes keeping all dates

Tags: r, date, dataframe, datatable

I have two dataframes (large ones) with dates in them. I would like to merge those dataframes keeping all the dates by sub_id, to create the most complete timeline possible, but the timeline has a rule. **If one of the SUB_ID's has a record in df_02, you need to replace the dates of df_01 for that SUB_ID, starting from the first END that's equal in both df's (the first available date in df_02 onwards)**. 
 in this example,for instance, i would need to replace the `226699` dates for SUB_ID `40843342` starting from `2006-12-31` onwards. 
I add the `dput()` of problematic cases:

df_01:

```
structure(list(ID = c(81, 226699, 226699, 226699, 226699, 226699, 
81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 226699, 226699, 226699, 226699, 226699, 226699, 
226699, 226699, 226699, 226699, 226699, 226699, 226699, 81, 81, 
81), SUB_ID = c(99026150L, 40843342L, 40843342L, 40843342L, 40843342L, 
40843342L, 40816464L, 40816464L, 40816464L, 40816464L, 40816464L, 
27415546L, 27415546L, 27415546L, 27415546L, 27415546L, 27415546L, 
27415546L, 27415546L, 27415546L, 27415546L, 27415546L, 27415546L, 
27415546L, 144910L, 144910L, 68340L), TYPE = c("1", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "4", "1", "1", "C", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), END = structure(c(16283, 
16678, 16313, 16225, 15278, 13513, 16343, 16313, 16282, 14699, 
14244, 2932896, 17837, 17378, 17166, 17074, 16678, 13969, 13725, 
13603, 13452, 13268, 13238, 13148, 2932896, 17712, 17531), class = "Date"), 
    START = structure(c(15065, 16314, 16226, 15279, 13514, 11778, 
    16314, 16283, 14700, 14245, 13514, 17838, 17379, 17167, 17075, 
    16679, 13970, 13726, 13604, 13453, 13269, 13239, 13149, 12874, 
    17713, 17532, 16344), class = "Date"), VALUE = c(3L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), ORIGIN = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(429970L, 2542937L, 2542964L, 
2542994L, 2543028L, 2543070L, 2810465L, 2810487L, 2810509L, 2810540L, 
2810565L, 5501774L, 5501800L, 5501828L, 5501856L, 5501882L, 5501912L, 
5501949L, 5501976L, 5502003L, 5502030L, 5502057L, 5502084L, 5502111L, 
14426231L, 14426236L, 15819358L), class = "data.frame")
```

df_02:

```
structure(list(ID= c(226699, 226699, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 
81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81), SUB_ID= c(40843342L, 40843342L, 40816464L, 
40816464L, 40816464L, 40816464L, 40816464L, 40816464L, 40816464L, 
40816464L, 40816464L, 40816464L, 40816464L), TYPE= c("B", "4", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), END= structure(c(13513, 
11992, 13513, 12325, 11991, 11960, 11777, 11503, 11473, 11412, 
11322, 11261, 10591), class = "Date"), START= structure(c(13453, 
11778, 12326, 11992, 11961, 11778, 11504, 11474, 11413, 11323, 
11262, 10592, 10317), class = "Date"), VALUE= c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), ORIGIN = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(207418L, 207420L, 
250797L, 250798L, 250799L, 250800L, 250801L, 250802L, 250803L, 
250804L, 250805L, 250806L, 250807L), class = "data.frame")
```

If I use `rbind(df_01,df_02)`, the ID 81 gets completed, but the data for ID `226699` gets poluted (I don't eliminate the dates after `2006-12-31`). On the other hand, if i join and apply a flag logic, get the correct timeline for `226699` but lose the dates for `81`

this is the flag logic I've been using:

```
df_final <- dplyr::full_join(df_01,df_02,by=c("ID","SUB_ID"))
df_final$flag <- ifelse(is.na(df_final$END.y),0,ifelse(df_final$END.x == df_final$END.y,1,0))
df_final <- df_final%>%group_by(SUB_ID)%>%mutate(dflag = cummax(flag == 1))
df_final$END_FINAL <-ifelse(df_final$dflag ==0,df_final$END.x,df_final$END.y) 
df_final$START_FINAL <- ifelse(df_final$dflag==0,df_final$START.x,df_final$START.y)
```

At the end, the dataframe should have the combination of all the dates of df_01 and df_02, if any END in df_02 is the same as the END in df_01, then from that moment, for that SUB_ID, the following dates should come from df_02 only:
 Basic example, in general lines for brevity. 
(Ordered by SUB_ID,START, descending)

```
df_final <- df_final[order(df_final$SUB_ID,df_final$START,decreasing = 
TRUE),]
df_final

ID     | SUB_ID   | TYPE | END         | START       | VALUE | ORIGIN
81     | 99026150 | 1    | 2014-08-01  | 2011-04-01  | 3     | 0  <-- df_01
81     | 40816464 | 1    | 2014-09-30  | 2014-09-01  | 3     | 0  <-- df_01
... The combination of df_01 and df_02 dates for this SUB_ID ....
... Ending with the last record for this SUB_ID in df_02 ........
81     | 40816464 | 1    | 1998-12-31  | 1998-04-01  | 3     | 1  <-- df_02
... The rest of the dates for this ID (that are in df_01) .......
226699 | 40843342 | 1    | 2015-08-31  | 2014-09-01  | 3     | 0  <-- df_01
... All the dates for this SUB_ID until it reaches 2006-12-31 ...
... Instead of ending with 2006-12-31 2002-04-01 ................
... it should end with the two lines of df_02 ...................
226699 | 40843342 | B    | 2006-12-31  | 2006-11-01  | 3     | 1  <-- df_02
226699 | 40843342 | 4    | 2002-11-01  | 2002-04-01  | 3     | 1  <-- df_02
... The rest of the dates for this ID (that are in df_01) .......
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The quickest and simplest way I can think of is to `merge` and `filter`.

Comment: @NelsonGon the flag logic is a merge and filter approach, but i can't figure out a way to properly keep all the necessary values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
require(tidyverse)
#nest data by SUB_ID
df_01 < - nest(df_01, -SUB_ID)
df_02 <- nest(df_02, -SUB_ID)

#Merge data by SUB_ID
df <- merge(df_01, df_02, by = "SUB_ID", all = TRUE) %>%
#if I have data for df_02 keep that data, if not,  keep data from df_01
  mutate(keep = ifelse(is.na(data.y) == TRUE, data.x, data.y)) %>% 
#remove data from each original df_01/02
  select(-data.x, -data.y) %>% 
#nest the data to keep
  unnest(keep)
```

In addition, if you'd like to "take" something from the original data in `df_01` or `df_02` you can just build a function and run it through `purrr::map2()`